# Can't restart a suspended process

Tags: zsh, python, macos, background-process

I execute a long running Python-process. To stop the annoying noise from the fans I use [AppPolice](https://github.com/AppPolice/AppPolice) to prevent this process from using more than 20 % CPU (I don't care when it finishes).

I think that when I "applied" AppPolice to this process this line was printed on stdout/stderr (interleaved with the other output from the process)

```
zsh: suspended (signal)  myPythonScript
```

An hour later or so I noticed that the prompt was back, despite the process not being finished (I know that from the output, the script outputs a "I am done"-message when it finishes), but nothing about "suspended" or similar just the expected output followed by a prompt:

```
normal output from the script
db@16 %
```

This was puzzling so I tried `fg`:

```
db@16 % fg
[1]  + continued  myPythonScript
zsh: suspended (signal)  myPythonScript
db@16 %
```

What???

The suspend happened instantaneously after the `fg`.

I tried a couple of more times, with the same result. It is like ctrl-z is automatically sent immediately after I `fg`.

What is going on here?

Comment: Looks like [AppPolice does send some SIGSTOP](https://github.com/AppPolice/AppPolice/blob/master/AppPolice/C/proc_cpulim.c#L360) and SIGCONT signals to enforce the CPU usage limit. If that's the case, `zsh` would be notified when the job is suspended upon SIGSTOP at which point its `wait()` would return. And the SIGCONT would resume it, but in background as zsh is no longer waiting for it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Would be interesting to know what method AppPolice use to limit CPU-usage, and if it can be emulated from the command line?